# Out of Memory when running a program in php

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I am running two almost identical programs with the exception that one needs to only look at the lowest price, the second needs to look at the lowest 4 prices and get the average.  my problem is that when running the second program, I get an out of memory php fatal error.  My hosting provider has set the memory limit to 3000M for me and I still get the error. 
Here is the code for the first program:

```
    $parsed_xml = amazon_xml($isbn);

$current = $parsed_xml->ListMatchingProductsResult->Products->Product;
$asin = $current->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN;
//print_r($asin);

// get information based on the items ASIN
$price_xml = amazonPrice_xml($asin, $ItemCondition);
$currentPrice = $price_xml ->GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing;
$listPrice = $currentPrice->Price->ListingPrice->Amount;

// check to see if there are values
if(!empty($listPrice))
{  
            //print_r($listPrice); die;
//if($currentPrice->Price->ListingPrice->Amount > 0) {
    while(count($lowestPrices) < 2)
    {

            foreach($currentPrice as $offer){ 
                $totalFeedback = $offer->SellerFeedbackCount;

                $condition = $offer->Qualifiers->ItemSubcondition;

                //amazon condition matching algorithm (so we can match our condition up against amazons conditions)
                switch ($condition) {
                case "New":
                    $amazonCondition = 5;
                    break;
                case "Mint":
                    $amazonCondition = 4;
                    break;
                case "VeryGood":
                    $amazonCondition = 3;
                    break;
                case "Good":
                    $amazonCondition = 2;
                    break;
                case "Acceptable":
                    $amazonCondition = 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    $amazonCondition = 0;
                } // end of switch statement

            //echo $condition . "|" . $ourCondition . "|" . $amazonCondition . "|" . count($lowestPrices) . "|" . $totalFeedback . "|" . $merchantId . "<br/>";

            /* default lowest 1 */
                if(count($lowestPricesDefault[$a] <2)){
                $lowestPricesDefault[$a] = str_replace('$','',$offer->Price->ListingPrice->Amount);
                $a++;
                }

                if( ($ourCondition <= $amazonCondition) && ($totalFeedback >= 1500) &&  (count($lowestPrices) <2) )
                {
                $lowestPrices[$x] = str_replace('$','',$offer->Price->ListingPrice->Amount);
                $x++;
                }

            }
        $z++;
    }


    if(count($lowestPrices) > 0){
        $avgPrice = (array_sum($lowestPrices)/count($lowestPrices)) - .10;
        $source = "Amazon Condition Price";
    }else{
        //$avgPrice = $listPrice - ($listPrice * 0.25);
        $avgPrice = (array_sum($lowestPricesDefault)/count($lowestPricesDefault)) - .10;
        $source = "Default Pricing";
    }

    //make sure avg price is atleast 5.50, >236% of follett price, and >=200% of our cost
    if($avgPrice < ($follettPrice * 2.37)){
        $avgPrice = $follettPrice * 2.37;
        $source = "Follett Pricing";
    }
    if($avgPrice < ($row['cost'] * 2)){
        $avgPrice = $row['cost'] * 2;
        $source = "Double Cost";
    }
    if($avgPrice < 5.50){
        $avgPrice = 5.50;
        $source = "Lowest Base Cost";
    }

    //update Prices
    $conn->query("UPDATE inventory SET ourPrice = $avgPrice WHERE sku=" . $row['sku']);
```

Here is the second program:

```
    $parsed_xml = amazon_xml($isbn);

$current = $parsed_xml->ListMatchingProductsResult->Products->Product;
$asin = $current->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN;

// get information based on the items ASIN
$price_xml = amazonPrice_xml($asin, $ItemCondition);
$currentPrice = $price_xml ->GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing;
$listPrice = $currentPrice->Price->ListingPrice->Amount;

// check to see if there are values
if(!empty($listPrice))
{  
//if($price_xml) {
    while(count($lowestPrices) < 4 ) // changed count to 4 per loralee's email 5-1-2012
    {


        foreach($currentPrice as $offer){
            $totalFeedback = $offer->SellerFeedbackCount;

            $condition = $offer->Qualifiers->ItemSubcondition;

                //amazon condition matching algorithm (so we can match our condition up against amazons conditions)
                switch ($condition) {
                case "New":
                    $amazonCondition = 5;
                    break;
                case "Mint":
                    $amazonCondition = 4;
                    break;
                case "VeryGood":
                    $amazonCondition = 3;
                    break;
                case "Good":
                    $amazonCondition = 2;
                    break;
                case "Acceptable":
                    $amazonCondition = 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    $amazonCondition = 0;
                }

            //echo $condition . "|" . $ourCondition . "|" . $amazonCondition . "|" . count($lowestPrices) . "|" . $totalFeedback . "|" . $merchantId . "<br/>";

            /* default lowest 4 */
            if(count($lowestPricesDefault[$a] < 4)){ //changed to 4 per new pricing specs
                $lowestPricesDefault[$a] = str_replace('$','',$offer->Price->ListingPrice->Amount);
                $a++;
            }

            if( ($ourCondition <= $amazonCondition) && ($totalFeedback >= 99) &&  (count($lowestPrices) < 4) ) //changed to 4 per new pricing specs
            {
                $lowestPrices[$x] = str_replace('$','',$offer->Price->ListingPrice->Amount);
                $x++;
            } 
        }
        $z++;
    }



    if(count($lowestPrices) > 0){
        $avgPrice = array_sum($lowestPrices)/count($lowestPrices);
        $source = "Amazon Condition Price";
    }else{
        //$avgPrice = $listPrice - ($listPrice * 0.25);
        $avgPrice = array_sum($lowestPricesDefault)/count($lowestPricesDefault);
        $source = "Default Pricing";
    }

    //make sure avg price is atleast 5.50, >236% of follett price, and >=200% of our cost
    if($avgPrice < ($follettPrice * 2.37)){
        $avgPrice = $follettPrice * 2.37;
        $source = "Follett Pricing";
    }
    if($avgPrice < ($row['cost'] * 2)){
        $avgPrice = $row['cost'] * 2;
        $source = "Double Cost";
    }
    if($avgPrice < 5.50){
        $avgPrice = 5.50;
        $source = "Lowest Base Cost";
    }

    //update fillzPrice
    $conn->query("UPDATE inventory SET ourPrice = $avgPrice WHERE sku=" . $row['sku']);
```

I have been getting the error on line 86 of the second program which is the condition line ($condition = $offer->Qualifiers->ItemSubcondition;) Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?  Also, does anyone have any suggestions to make it run any better?

Comment: You might want to ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why do you set `$lowestPrices = 0`, when everywhere else you're treating it as an array?

Comment: Why not just sort the prices then pick the earliest *n* indices?

Comment: @andrewsi I was trying to set it to something to see if it would keep working if there was no information for lowestPrices.

Comment: @Jim you should set the default to the same data type as you're expecting. In this case, an `array`.

Comment: Is `while(count($lowestPrices) < 4 ) ` a infinite loop?

Comment: What happens is there are only 3 $lowestPrices? It looks like the first program will halt, and the second run forever...

Comment: Matt Thanks, just posted it there as well.  @iserni the first program runs perfectly, the second stops with an out of memeory error.

Comment: Off topic, but your SQL code `$conn->query(...)` should be using parameterised queries rather than string concatenation to insert the variables into the query.

Comment: @SDC While parameterised queries are good practise in general, they're hardly essential for a case like this. There are plenty of other best practices not being followed here, but for some reason people always feel particularly aggrieved by non-parameterised SQL.

Comment: For big file, perfect use XMLReader(SAX event based parser) class. But if liked simplexml syntax: https://github.com/dkrnl/SimpleXMLReader/blob/master/library/SimpleXMLReader.php Usage example: http://github.com/dkrnl/SimpleXMLReader/blob/master/examples/example1.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, two code-review points:

1. You have variables `$a`, `$x`, and `$z`, all with no initial condition, and all entirely opaque to anyone trying to maintain the code. A single `$i` as a loop-counter is commonly considered acceptable, but good variable-naming can make debugging a lot easier.
2. When using SimpleXML, always cast values to a string: `$asin = $current->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN;` should read `$asin = (string)$current->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN;` Among other things, forgetting to do this will mean that `$asin` could never be saved to a session (since SimpleXML objects cannot be serialized).

As for why your code is failing, I think the structure of your loops is wrong:

```
while(count($lowestPrices) < 4 )
{
    foreach($currentPrice as $offer)
    {
        // Do something which may add to `$lowestPrices`
        $z++;
    }
}
```

Firstly, `$z` doesn't seem to be used for anything. Secondly, `$lowestPrices` may be added to 0, 1, 4, or even 100 times inside the `foreach` loop. If it is added to at least 4 times, the `while` loop will immediately exit (so might as well not exist); if it is added to less than 4 times, the `foreach` loop will simply be run again over the same data. It's not clear to me that this will make it any more likely to meet the condition of the `while` loop, giving you an infinite loop.

The reason you're running out of memory, rather than just CPU time, is the additional array `$lowestPricesDefault` grows even when `$lowestPrices` doesn't, so it will carry on growing indefinitely every time the `while` loop (and therefore the whole inner `foreach` loop) repeats.

Comment: Thanks IMSoP, I did initialize the variables, just didn't add it to the code to save a little space.  I had cast the values to a string in another program, and I kept getting a fatal error, but when removed it worked fine which is why it is not done here.  I am a little confused about how I should remedy my situation based on your comments.

Comment: Not sure what problem you were having with casting to string, but I would definitely recommend figuring it out, as you will store up trouble for later if you leave everything as SimpleXML objects. As for fixing this code, maybe you can simply remove the while loop - AFAICS, nothing different will happen on the second, third, or one hundredth time round that loop that will help you reach your target of 4 prices.

Comment: Thanks!!!  getting rid of the while loop did the trick.  I will look into the casting issue and see if I can get something to work right.